# Unable to get value from value stack in struts2 using <s:action>

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, valuestack

**What I want:** I want to retrieve the value from `List` collection.

I’m practicing/learning struts 2 framework. But, I am confused about `OGNL` behavior.
These are my files:

**Index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <hr>
    <s:action name="one" />
    <s:property value="list_fruits[0]" />
</body>
</html>
```

**MyAction.java**

```
package abc;

import java.util.*;
import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.RequestMap;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.*;

public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
    private List list_fruits;

    public List getList_fruits() {
        return list_fruits;
    }

    public void setList_fruits(List list_fruits) {
        this.list_fruits = list_fruits;
    }

    public String doOne() {
        list_fruits = new ArrayList();
        list_fruits.add("banana");
        list_fruits.add("apple");
        list_fruits.add("mango");

        /*RequestMap rm = (RequestMap) ActionContext.getContext().get("request");
        rm.put("req_scope", list_fruits);*/
        return "sendToOne";
    }
}
```

**one.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>ONE.JSP</h1>
    <br>
    <s:property value="list_fruits[0]" />
</body>
</html>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="vns" extends="struts-default">

        <action name="one" class="abc.MyAction" method="doOne">
            <result name="sendToOne">/one.jsp</result>
        </action>

    </package>
</struts>
```

I am experiencing following behaviors:

**Case1**: When I put this (below) code in `index.jsp`, I get ***NO*** value printed.

```
<s:action name="one"/>
<s:property value="list_fruits[0]"/>
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

**Case2**: When I put this (below) code in `index.jsp`, the value gets printed from `one.jsp` because in this scene I included attribute `executeResult=”true”`

```
<s:action name="one" executeResult="true"/>
<s:property value="list_fruits[0]"/>    <!-- still NOT printed here, but gets printed from one.jsp -->
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

**Case3**: When I put this (below) code in `MyAction.java` and `index.jsp`, then the value get printed on screen (`index.jsp`).

***MyAction.java***

```
RequestMap rm=(RequestMap)ActionContext.getContext().get("request");    
rm.put("req_scope", list_fruits);
```

***index.jsp***

```
<s:action name="one"/> <!-- removed executeResult="true" -->
<s:property value="#request.req_scope[0]"/>
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

in Case2 value gets printed due to `one.jsp` and not due to `index.jsp`

I want to know why I am NOT getting any value printed in **Case1** whereas in Case2 and Case3, there is no such problem. Why is it so? Can anyone guide me?

Comment: you have to give the value or list reference for print the value to <s:property /> and In scene 1 you did not set the property for action tag to show the executed result and not set the list reference properly manner as per OGNL so you didnt get the result.

Comment: In **scene 1**, I've given the reference of list in `value` attribute on `<s:property>`. Just not given boolean `executeResult`, 'coz its not compulsory. Scene3 is also same, then why it gets printed in scene3 and not in scene1?

Comment: Scope, scope and scope. It is not printed in index because it doesn't exists. BTW the OGNL is not related at all.

Comment: can you tell me how scope works here.. I, mean why there is no scope problem in case2, while case1 suffers due to "scope". How does scope works here.

Comment: @AleksandrM , I want to ask 2 questions: **Ist**: Did the List entered in `value stack` in case1. **IInd** Am I getting the value from value stack in case2. I am stuck, please clarify.

Comment: Action is created for every request.

Comment: @AleksandrM still not clear. :(  please explain.

Comment: @AlexanderM,Did you say the new valuestack is created for each request?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5037561/1700321

Comment: @Madhesh in all 3 cases I am hitting the Action class's execute method, that means request is made in all 3 cases. I want to know, isn't the List entered in value stack when request was made in case1. How is scope (as mentioned by AleksandrM in previous comments) is differ in case1 and case2. How is request made through <s:action> and <s:form> differs? Can you guide me?

Comment: @JSK You should not access JSPs directly, Struts is used to forward to the JSPs. If it's static then it can't work without action context.

Answer (score 1):

AleksandrM already answered you, but since you said

> still not clear. :( please explain.

You can use it for :

1. calling an Action and use `executeResult="true"` to get the result;
2. calling an Action and push it on the main page ValueStack with `var` attribute, then reference it with `#` :

   ```xml
   <s:action   name="one"       var="instance" /> 
   <s:property value="#instance.list_fruits[0]"/>
   ```
3. calling an Action that sets something in request / session scope, and then retrieve those values by using `#attr` or `#session`;
4. calling an Action that *does something* (e.g. persists into the database the timestamp of when the page has been opened).

**But you can do any of this single things server side, and BETTER.**

This is why you shouldn't use the `<s:action/>` tag: it breaks most of the S2 framework conventions and mechanisms and it is a bad practice (or at least it isn't a good one).